# File Transfer Logging & Security

Tags: windows, ftp

I am looking to send the files out from my server. (Windows 2003) I understand a common way is to use FTP to transfer the files out.

I would like to ask if there are any other mechanisms out there which would allow me to achieve the same objectives ?

I would also like to ask if there are any default mechanisms put in place to log the transfer details of the file being sent out from the server. Example, which file was accessed, which file was been transferred out from the server?

Comment: There are myriad ways to achieve this, including SFTP, HTTP/S, and others. What is your end goal?

Comment: Why not just use FTP? It's what it was made for.. Grab a copy of Filezilla FTP Server and be happy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a web server on your server, create a page with links to the files, and then just use the server logs to show you who downloaded what and when.  If you want it more secure, you could put the page behind an .htaccess file.

If you just want to make sense of the FTP logs generated by the FTP server built into your server, you can use the [Microsoft Log Parser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659).  Here's a [nice article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/robert_mcmurray/detecting-ftp-leeches-with-logparser) about detecting FTP leechers on the FTP server, just for a different viewpoint.  This [little thread at iis.net](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97cbe127-bcb2-462d-9bdd-11679616f78b/trying-to-decipher-iis-60-logs-to-locate-reason-for-a-401?forum=iis56troubleshooting#1982682)  also links to the parser, as well as some other tools to help sort out that log.